# sphinx python with boost-python library not found

Tags: python, python-sphinx, boost-python

I'm trying to use sphinx to generate documentation for a package that I wrote. Everything was working great until I added some code that used another package I wrote that wraps some boost-python modules.

Now when I run `make html` I get this (edited for clarity):

```
$ make html
sphinx-build -b html -d build/doctrees   source build/html
Running Sphinx v1.3.1
loading pickled environment... done
building [mo]: targets for 0 po files that are out of date
building [html]: targets for 0 source files that are out of date
updating environment: 0 added, 1 changed, 0 removed
reading sources... [100%] my_project
/path/to/my_project/my_project/docs/source/my_project.rst:19: WARNING: autodoc: failed to import module u'my_project.my_module'; the following exception was raised:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/harding/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Sphinx-1.3.1-py2.7.egg/sphinx/ext/autodoc.py", line 385, in import_object
    __import__(self.modname)
  File "/path/to/my_project/__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
    from . import module_that_uses_boost_python_classes
  File "/path/to/module_that_uses_boost_python_classes.py", line 10, in <module>
    import package_that_wraps_boost_python_classes
  File "/path/to/package_that_wraps_boost_python_classes/__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    from native_boost_python_module import *
ImportError: dlopen(/path/to/native_boost_python_module.so, 2): Library not loaded: cpp_library.dylib
  Referenced from: /path/to/native_boost_python_module.so
  Reason: image not found
```

The problem is that when sphinx trys to import my module, it fails to load the linked c++ library from my boost-python related package. That package is installed via `pip` and it loads fine in all other situations.

I manually specified the full path to all the c++ libraries with `install_name_tool -change` and then sphinx works fine.

My question is this: how can I get sphinx to import my boost-python package without manually editing the c++ libraries manually with `install_name_tool`?

I have `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` set to include the directory that contains all the c++ libraries.

I'm on MacOS Sierra

Comment: A wild guess if you haven't tried it yet: is it possible that maybe you are importing something you don't mean to import? and that's what causing the error? You have the statement `from native_boost_python_module import *` - perhaps if you narrow down the imports only to the modules you surely have, then maybe it will solve the import error?